# CSS text in td same size and alignment as text in a field in other td

Tags: html, css

I notice that, when text and <input type="text"> fields run in the same line, the two texts are vertically aligned with one another.  This in my opinion is a good thing.

This is NOT always the case with text that is laid out in a table with say two columns, labels on left and inputs on the right.  Usually, one will be lower.

Without having to micro-manage padding which I'd have to adjust if I ever change font size, is there any elegant way to align vertically regular text in one td, and the value of an input field in the td next to it?

Comment: Can you post some code demonstrating what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.  It looks good to me:

http://jsfiddle.net/54PK9/

```
outside table <input type="text" value="test" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            inside table
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="test" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Perhaps you can fork the above fiddle and show us what you mean?

However, if you need to adjust, say, inputs inside a td, something like this should work without having to adjust too much (note: .1 may be not quite the right number):

```
.table-with-a-certain-class td > input
{
    margin-top: -.1em;
}
```